# I can't align my div's next to eachother

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I have 2 div's, that are within a div. Like in the code:

Html:

```
    <div class="main" style="clear: both;">
        <div class="text">
        /text is here
        </div>    
        <div class="sponsors">
            <img src="images/Sponsors/asfalpan.png" alt="Asfalpan" width="285">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.main {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#232021;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.text {
    width: 700px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position:relative;
    font-family: Gisha;
    color: white;
    font-size:14px;
 }
.sponsors {
    margin-left: 710px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Gisha;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #E5173E;
}
```

So I want the .sponsors and .text to be next to each other in .main
but for some reason, this doesn't happen. they appear under eachother. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left;` and perhaps a width, to each of them

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dLcjy/2/)

Learn more here....

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/